# Induction : Prove $a^k-b^k \le ka^{k-1}(a-b)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I am doing revision for my discrete mathematics and I am having a really hard time with this question. Suppose that a,b are real numbers with $0<b<a$. Prove by mathematical induction that if $k$ is a positive integer then $a^k-b^k \le ka^{k-1}(a-b)$

I know this is a duplicate question that has been answered , but I can't wrap my head around the given solutions.

I especially do not understand how : $a^{k+1} - b^{k+1} = a^k(a-b) + b(a^k-b^k)$

I also tried using the hint : $a^k - b^k = (a-b)(a^{k-1} + a^{k-2}b + ... + b^{k-1}) $

I am really lost with this , could someone point me in the right direction please ?

Comment: What are a,b,n and k?

Comment: $a^k(a−b)+b(a^k−b^k)=a^{k+1}−a^kb+a^kb−b^{k+1}$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA i know it expands out like this , but how did $a^{k+1} - b^{k+1}$ factor into that specifically ?

Comment: I have edited the question , hope that it is clearer now

Comment: $k$ and $n$ or only $k$?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla sorry mistake on my part , its just k

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint without Induction:** Consider
$$
a^k-b^k=\overbrace{\left(\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}a^jb^{k-1-j}\right)}^{\le ka^{k-1}}\,(a-b)
$$

---

**Hint for Induction:**
$$
a^{k+1}-b^{k+1}=a^k(a-b)+\overbrace{\ \ \ \ \ \ b\vphantom{a^k}\ \ \ \ \ \ }^{\le a}\,\overbrace{\left(a^k-b^k\right)}^{\le ka^{k-1}(a-b)}
$$

Comment: actually this has not been covered at all in my lectures , am I suppose to know this beforehand , or will there be a way to do it without using this formula ?

Comment: @BákaVíncentHóng actually it seems like you already mentioned it in your question.

Comment: @rah4927 the thing is i do not know how to proceed $a^k−b^k=(a−b)(a^{k−1}+a^{k−2}b+...+b^{k−1})$ . How does this relate to $a^{k+1}−b^{k+1}=(a−b)(a^{k}+a^{k−1}b+...+b^{k})$ and the induction hypothesis ?

Comment: I quote from your question: $a^k - b^k = (a-b)(a^{k-1} + a^{k-2}b + ... + b^{k-1})$

Comment: You don't need induction if you use this: each term in the summation is less than $a^{k-1}$.

Comment: @robjohn I'm terribly sorry, but the question asks for a proof using induction , I'm really lost at this point , been going at it for 1 hour+ and I just don't see it

Comment: $a^{k+1} - b^{k+1} = a.a^k - b.b^k$ , the part i do not understand is how did it become the equation you have given ?

Comment: @BákaVíncentHóng: Do you see that $a^{k+1}-b^{k+1}=a^k(a-b)+b\left(a^k-b^k\right)$? Just multiply the terms and add. If you see that, then my second hint should prove the inductive step.

Comment: @robjohn yes I do see that , but is there a specific "rule" for this equivalency? I wouldn't had known that this is the way to solve the problem if I did not refer to the solutions .

Comment: @BákaVíncentHóng: I'm not sure what you mean by "rule", but you want to write $a^{k+1}-b^{k+1}$ in terms of a formula with $a^k-b^k$ and use the inductive hypothesis that $a^k-b^k\le ka^{k-1}(a-b)$. The hint was given so that this can be done.

Comment: @robjohn Oh I think I finally get it. I thought that there was some theorem for it . So I need to figure out how to transform it into a form so that I can apply the inductive hypothesis . Thanks so much for your help !

Answer (score 3):

No need for induction to prove this inequality:

If you've seen the formula for the *geometric series*, you probably noticed it is deduced from the algebraic (high-school) formula:
$$1-x^n=(1-x)(1+x+\dots +x^{n-1}).$$
Setting $x=\dfrac ba$, you obtain
\begin{align}
a^n-b^n&=a^n\Bigl(1-\frac ba\Bigr)\Bigl(1+\frac ba+\dots\frac{b^{n-1}}{a^{n-1}}\Bigr)\\
&=a\Bigl(1-\frac ba\Bigr)\,a^{n-1}\Bigl(1+\frac ba+\dots\frac{b^{n-1}}{a^{n-1}}\Bigr)\\[0.5ex]
&=(a-b)\bigl(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\dots+b^{n-1}\bigr)
\end{align}
This formula can be rewritten as
$$a^n-b^n=(a-b)\sum_{\!i+j=n-1}a^ib^j\!\!$$
Now, since $0<b<a$, for each $(i,j)$, $\;a^ib^j\le a^ia^j=a^{n-1}$, and the sum has $n$ terms, so:
$$a^n-b^n\le(a-b)\sum_{\!i+j=n-1}a^{n-1}=(a-b)na^{n-1}$$

*A proof by a (direct) induction:*

Starting from the relation:
\begin{align}
a^{k+1}-b^{k+1}&=a^k(a-b)+(a^k-b^k)b\\
&<a^k(a-b)+ ka^{k-1}(a-b)b&&\text{by the inductive hypothesis}\\
&<a^k(a-b)+ ka^{k}(a-b)&&\text{since 0<b<a}\\
&=(k+1)a^k(a-b).
\end{align}

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, but this question specifically asked for mathematical induction to prove the statement

Comment: Prove the formula for $1-x^n$ by induction? That is the crux of the proof.

Answer (score 2):

$a^k-b^k\le ka^{k-1}(a-b).$

Step: $k+1$.

$a^{k+1}-b^{k+1} = $

$a^k(a-b) +b(a^k-b^k) \le$

$a^k(a-b) +bka^{k-1}(a-b)=$

$(a-b)(a^k +bka^{k-1}) \lt $

$(a-b)(a^k +ka^k) =$

$(a-b)(1+k)a^k.$

Used:

$0 \lt b \lt a$, and

$a^{k+1}-b^{k+1} = $

$a^k(a-b) +b(a^k-b^k).$

Comment: how did $a^{k+1} - b^{k+1} = a^k(a-b) + b(a^k-b^k)$ ? I'm having a really hard time seeing it

Comment: Vincent: RHS:a^k(a-b) = (a^k)a -(a^k)b , distributive law, get rid of parenthesis. The other term: b(a^k-b^k)= ba^k -bb^k= ba^k -b^{k+1}. Now look at the (a^k)b terms , opposite sign, they cancel. Ok now?

Answer (score 1):

Consider function $f(x)=x^k$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and segment $[b,a]$, $b,a>0$. Then apply Lagrange's theorem:
$$a^k-b^k=(x^k)'|_{x=\xi}(a-b)=k\xi^{k-1}(a-b),$$
where $\xi\in(b,a)$. Due to monotonic increase of $f'(x)=kx^{k-1}$ one gets
$$a^k-b^k=k\xi^{k-1}(a-b)\leqslant ka^{k-1}(a-b)$$
**UPD** Sorry, I didn't notice that you have to prove this using induction, I'll leave this answer anyway

Answer (score 0):

Actually the part you didn't understand simply means adding and subtracting a term $b a^k$which makes no change to the expression. Then the terms are regrouped.